# EF6 - Cannot Mock Return Value for ObjectResult<T> for Unit Test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, entity-framework-6, moq

I have code similar to this in a method that I'm trying to unit test:

```
return _context.usp_get_Some_Data(someStringParam).FirstOrDefault();
```

The stored procedure call return type:

```
ObjectResult<usp_get_Some_Data_Result>.
```

In my unit test, I'm trying to do something like this (using NUnit and Moq):

```
var procResult = new ObjectResult<usp_get_Some_Data_Result>();
mockContext.Setup(m => m.usp_get_Some_Data(It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Returns(procResult);
```

However, I'm not able to create an instance of ObjectResult (this is `System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectResult<T>`, not the older `System.Data.Objects` one). It doesn't have a public parameterless constructor, but the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt154818(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectResult%601.) says it has a protected one. From my testing, he documentation appears to be incorrect.

**What I've tried**

I've tried creating a derived class and calling `base()` on the constructor, and I've also tried using reflection (both `Activator.CreateInstance` and invoking the `ConstructorInfo` with `BindingFlags` of `NonPublic`, all of which have failed (it appears from my debugging this that the type does have three private constructors, all of which have 3 or more parameters, but unfortunately it looks like a major effort to figure out what is actually required for these parameters).

I've also tried creating an `IEnumerable<usp_get_Some_Data_Result>` and casting it to `ObjectResult<usp_get_Some_Data_Result>`, but the cast fails. In addition, I've tried something like

```
var mockObjectResult = new Mock<ObjectResult<usp_get_Some_Data_Result>>();
```

Pretty much everything I've tried fails with a similar error about a default constructor not being available.

**Question**

Is there any way to create an instance of `ObjectResult<T>` for unit testing, or is there any other type that I can create that can be successfully cast to `ObjectResult<T>`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something, but can't you just do this:

```
class TestableObjectResult<T> : ObjectResult<T>
{
}
```

And then in your test:

```
var mockObjectResult = new Mock<TestableObjectResult<usp_get_Some_Data_Result>>();
```

MockObject does have a protected constructor, you don't really have to do anything to call it, since it doesn't have any parameters, the auto-wiring will take care of it when you construct the testable version, so I'm not sure what you mean by you're "calling base() on the constructor"...

If I right click on ObjectResult and select goto definition the top of the file looks like this:

```
public class ObjectResult<T> : ObjectResult, IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable, IDbAsyncEnumerable<T>, IDbAsyncEnumerable
{
    // Summary:
    //     This constructor is intended only for use when creating test doubles that
    //     will override members with mocked or faked behavior. Use of this constructor
    //     for other purposes may result in unexpected behavior including but not limited
    //     to throwing System.NullReferenceException.
    protected ObjectResult();
```

Comment: The above class declaration that inherits from ObjectResult<T> fails to compile: "Error 1 The type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectResult<T>' has no constructors defined" I get the same error if I add a constructor to the TestableObjectResult class.

Comment: @dgavian Which version of EF are you using?  I've just ran it through a fresh fetch from nuget and it compiles fine.

Comment: @dgavian I've added the top of the source to my answer to demonstrate it should be there.. right click on it and goto definition.  If you're is different, then you may not be using the version you think you are...

Comment: That is odd. I didn't think updating from 6.1.0 to 6.1.3 would make that much of a difference, but it does compile now. Thanks!

Comment: I tried this in NSubstitute and it compiles but I get an error that "the result of a query cannot be enumerated more than once". Here is my line of code:
_dashboard.GetSummary(null, null, null)              .ReturnsForAnyArgs(new TestableObjectResult<GetSummary_Result>());

Comment: This is great. In addition, to really be able to test now that we've got that ObjectResult wrapped, we'll need an enumerator.
I'm adding an answer to cover the enumerator implementation to allow testing some fake data.

Comment: ObjectResult<T> Class is a sealed class ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.objects.objectresult-1?view=netframework-4.7.2  ) so how is inheritance possible? Which version of System.Data are you using?

Comment: @crazyTech as stated in the quesiton/comments above, this is referring to the ObjectResult from entity framework, version 6.  https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/blob/master/src/EntityFramework/Core/Objects/ObjectResult%60.cs

Answer (score 1):

As noted, I'm adding this answer to cover creating the Enumerator so the above can actually test some fake data:

Within the [TestFixture] class, create a method like the following:

```
private static IEnumerator<usp_get_Some_Data_Result> GetSomeDataResultEnumerator()
{
    yield return FakeSomeDataResult.Create(1, true);
    yield return FakeSomeDataResult.Create(2, false);
}
```

As provided in the previous answer, this handy little wrapper class allows instantiating the ObjectResult:

```
public class TestableObjectResult<T> : ObjectResult<T> { }
```

As provided in the previous answer, within the [SetUp] method:

```
var mockObjectResult = new Mock<TestableObjectResult<usp_get_Some_Data_Result>>();
```

Following this new Mock creation, set it up to return the Enumerator:

```
mockObjectResult.Setup(d => d.GetEnumerator()).Returns(GetSomeDataResultEnumerator());
```

Now the OP can return some fake data from the mockContext without it throwing a null reference exception when trying to get the enumerator:

```
mockContext.Setup(m => m.usp_get_Some_Data(It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Returns(mockObjectResult);
```

BTW, 
I'm just using a helper class to construct my fake data, to eliminate redundancy:

```
public static class FakeSomeDataResult
{
    public static usp_get_Some_Data_Result Create(int index)
    {
        return new usp_get_Some_Data_Result
        {
            SomeFriendlyNameProperty = string.Format("Some Data Result {0}", index),
        };
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As @forsvarir mentioned, you can create a TestableObjectResult class and override the GetEnumerator() to return whatever you want.

Something like this:

```
private class TestableObjectResult : ObjectResult<Animal>
    {
        public override IEnumerator<Animal> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return new List<Animal>() { new Animal(), new Animal() }.GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

## Here is my solution.

*It has seemed to work for me so far.*

```
public static class MoqExtentions
{
    public static void SetupReturn<T>(this Mock<ObjectResult<T>> mock, T whatToReturn)
    {
        IEnumerator<T> enumerator = ((IEnumerable<T>) new T[] {whatToReturn}).GetEnumerator();

        mock.Setup(or => or.GetEnumerator())
            .Returns(() => enumerator);
    }
}
```

Now you can mock a `ObjectResult<T>` and call the extention method that sets up the `ObjectResult<T>` to return whatever you pass into the extention method. Then the mocked `ObjectResult<T>` can be passed to a mocked `DbContext` method setup as the return value of the method call. And if needed, that can be passed to a mocked repo method that accessess the `ObjectResult<T>`.

*Here is an test example of using the mocked `ObjectResult<string>`*

```
    public void MockObjectResultReturn_OfString_Test()
    {
        // arrange
        const string shouldBe = "Hello World!";
        var sut = new Mock<ObjectResult<string>>();

        // act
        sut.SetupReturn<string>(shouldBe);

        //assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(sut);
        Assert.IsNotNull(sut.Object);
        Assert.AreEqual(shouldBe, sut.Object?.FirstOrDefault());
    }
```